# How to speedUp Random selecting in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, random, ssms

I have a table for phone numbers like this :

```
ID          PhoneNumber          Enabled GrupID CountryID
----------- -------------------- ------- ------ -----------
10444       ***001000999         1       NULL   1
10445       ***001000998         1       NULL   1
10446       ***001000994         1       NULL   1
10447       ***001000990         1       NULL   1
10448       ***001000989         1       NULL   1
```

This table has 68992507 rows.

I want to select some random phone number from it.

I can get my random number query by this stored procedure:

here I select random numbers, insert to a `@table` and then update the selected numbers .

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[Mysp_GetRandom]
    @countryid int,
    @count int
as
    declare @tbl table([ID] [int] , 
                       [PhoneNumber] [nchar](20) NOT NULL,
                       [Enabled] [bit] NULL,
                       [GrupID] [tinyint] NULL,
                       [CountryID] [int] NULL)

    INSERT INTO @tbl
        SELECT TOP (@count) *
        FROM tblPhoneNumber
        WHERE CountryID = @countryid 
          AND GrupID is null
        ORDER BY binary_checksum(ID * rand())

    UPDATE tblPhoneNumber 
    SET GrupID = 1 
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM @tbl)

    SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

The problem is that it takes a long time for the query to run. For example this query takes 12:30 minutes ...

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[Mysp_GetRandom]
            @countryid = 14, @count = 3

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value
```

and I have an ndex on this table :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-20150415-172433] 
ON [dbo].[tblPhoneNumber] ([CountryID] ASC)
         WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
               SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
               ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Execution plan is as below :

[image]

Thanks ...

Comment: try including all the required column in include clause of NC index. Partitioning table based on country ID will also help, if you have enterprise edition.

Comment: Execution plan is already giving you hing on adding missing index. Try adding that, it will help.

Comment: @AbhayChauhan add another column to index key column or included column ?

Comment: Add grupID to index key column and add other required columns in include clause

Comment: If you run your query with execution plan, and click on missing index "green text"; you will get the option to generate script for missing index. That should be simple.

Comment: I Run it on executation plan and also in .net app ,  @AbhayChauhan let me test it :)

Comment: Cool. Post the results for us

Comment: Think about it - you're giving the server no choice. Whatever you do, it has to visit every single row of the table to assign a random number to it. Indexes, etc, aren't going to help - there's no shortcut to avoid visiting every row here.

Comment: OH shet :D thank you @AbhayChauhan the query get just 00:11 second :)

Comment: Ohh great, I will post it as answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add grupID to index key column and add other required columns in include clause of your NC index NonClusteredIndex-20150415-172433.

Execution plan is already giving you the same hint on adding missing index.

P.S Mark it as answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your query plan, the first INSERT statement takes almost 100% of the time, and 70% of it is sorting. There's not much you can do with it since you already using `BINARY_CHECKSUM`. May be the table was filled in random enough manner to get off with taking consecutive rows starting from random offset, like this:

```
SELECT ID FROM tblPhoneNumber WHERE CountryID = @countryid 
      AND GrupID is null ORDER BY ID OFFSET CONVERT(int, 
      rand()*(select count(*) from  tblPhoneNumber)-@count-1) 
      ROWS FETCH NEXT @count ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace your order by clause.

You could create fairly random ids:

```
declare @count int = 100
; with ids(id, hex) as (
    Select 1, convert(bigint, convert(varbinary, '0x'+right(newid(), 6), 1 )) 
    Union all
    Select id+1, convert(bigint, convert(varbinary, '0x'+right(newid(), 6), 1 )) 
    From ids 
    Where id+1 <= @count 
)
Select * from ids
Option (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Then you can join it table with your table on ID.

You should review your indexes (mentionned by others) and add an index on phone Id.